# Android Environment Variable Setup in Windows 8.1

Tags: java, android, environment-variables

installed jdk1.7 in my machine and I setup environment variable for jdk its working fine
How to set up environment variable Android_Home in windows 
 and 

How to check that whether android environment variable is properly set or not
For java we use javac command to check the java environment setup like I need to find for android too
can any one knows about this 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You add / change the environment variable the same way you do with JAVA_HOME. To check if it's properly set you can type this in the command-line:

```
echo %ANDROID_HOME%
```

You should see the path to your sdk displayed.

I noticed, however, that sometimes this doesn't work, you can also go to Windows Explorer and type `%ANDROID_HOME%` in the path box, and press enter. If it opens the sdk directory it works ok.